# Is there a way to get a dict's keys as a list if no key is specified?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, type-conversion

I want to accomplish something like this:

```
>>> fruits = {'banana': 'yellow', 'pear': 'green'}
>>> fruits['banana']
'yellow'
>>> fruits
['banana', 'pear']
>>> fruits['pear']
'green'
```

Take note that I don't want to call `fruits.keys()`, just `fruits`. Normally it'd return the full dict, but is there any tricks I can use to make it become a list like that?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? `fruits` is a dictionary, if you are using the interactive interpreter and you type only `fruits` you will get the whole dictionary, but if you want to check if a certain key is present, you can do `if 'banana' in fruits:` and it will act like a list.... if you want to display the list of keys, you will *need* to use `keys()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the printed representation to change, inherit from `dict` and override `__repr__`:

```
class FruitDict(dict):
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.keys())

>>> fruits = FruitDict(banana='yellow', pear='green')
>>> fruits['banana']
'yellow'
>>> fruits
['pear', 'banana']
```

This will, however, not make fruits "become a list", only tweak the interactive printed representation to emulate one. If you need `fruits` to behave like a list, you will need to give more details about which list characteristics you want it to have.